# Send Text along with image in whatsapp api

Tags: php, whatsapp

This is my code:

```
 $w->sendMessageImage($target, "test.jpg");
```

It sends image without problem, Now I want to add some description along with the image.Any suggestions please.

Comment: We have absolutely no other context, which `whatsapp` api are you using? Have you gone through its documentation?

Comment: @VivekPradhan I'm using venomou's WhatAPI `https://github.com/venomous0x/WhatsAPI`  I checked the docs but i didn't found any info related to my context.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the source on GitHub and I don't think that you can.

Function parameters:

```
public function sendMessageImage($to, $filepath, $storeURLmedia = false, $fsize = 0, $fhash = "")
```

Comment: I checked this. There is no param to put my image description to send.